# About Firebase real time database

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on Firebase real time databases in Flutter. I am storing user information and their corresponding data in database. My code is given below:

```
//User Auth Class

class UserAuth{
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String token;

  UserAuth({@required this.id, @required this.email, @required this.token});
}

//User Details Class for storing data of corresponding user

class UserDetails{
  final String userDetailsId;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  UserDetails({@required this.userDetailsId,@required this.name, @required this.email});
}

//I am using this code to add userDetails in database.

  List<UserDetails> _detailsList = [];
  UserDetails _details;

Future<bool> addUserDetails(String username, String email) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    final Map<String, dynamic> userDetails = {
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
    };
    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
          'https://intro-to-firebase-711d4.firebaseio.com/Users.json',
          body: json.encode(userDetails));

      if (response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return false;
      }

      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      _details = UserDetails(
          userDetailsId: responseData['name'], name: username, email: email);

      _detailsList.add(_details);
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Now I want to get the following highlighted ids of the user so how to fetch it. I am using scoped model as a state management in Flutter.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I did it with javascript so far but in the documentation it seems not taht different for flutter:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0

This is the example shown in the docs. with `.child('users')` you can get the right section `.child(userId)` gives you access to the values.

All you have to do now is defining the variable `userId`

**flutter**

you can achieve this as follows

```
  stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child('users')            
        .equalTo(userId)
        .onValue,
```